# what is meant by symmetric DDA?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, line-drawing, dda

I have read about [DDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_%28graphics_algorithm%29). But I just came across the term *symmetric DDA*. What is it ? How is it different from *DDA* ?

Comment: where did you run into the term 'symmetric DDA'?

Comment: @Colin D I heard two people talking about the term.

Comment: you should stop and ask them next time you run into them!

Comment: @Colin D sure,if I see them one more time.I heard them talking in the train. _Instead of posting these chatty comments ,why don't you try answering it._

Comment: I'm sure it's in my copy of Principles Of Interactive Computer Graphics by Newman & Sproull, but I can't remember where the book is, so google will have to help: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fGX8yC-4vXUC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=symmetric+DDA&source=bl&ots=wa9HS0Nh_v&sig=xO8F-8n0UTK0Gw-an7AodlhrTis&sa=X&ei=MIQuUNCBM-GQ0AWyp4H4DA&ved=0CBoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20DDA&f=false

Comment: Here another link: http://books.google.de/books?id=3BPZXYlInKwC&pg=PT120&lpg=PT120&dq=symmetric+dda&source=bl&ots=FKIyIsfDrB&sig=IQDGj1uLMiMpMW375QjQUFiQnBs&hl=de&sa=X&ei=c48uUIecJNTa4QSSloGIBg&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=symmetric%20dda&f=false

Comment: @Y.E.P Or you could, you know, google it. Typing "symmetric DDA" into Google returned thousands of results.

Comment: @user1118321 really ? did you try it ? got there from something ?

Comment: @Y.E.P Yes. In fact, the very PDF quoted below in Ujjwal Singh's answer was the 2nd or 3rd hit.

Answer (score 5):

The DDA (Digital Differential Analyzer) algorithm is used to find out interpolating points between any given two points, linearly (i.e. straight line). Now since this is to be done on a digital computer - speed is an important factor.

The equation of a straight line is given by m=Δx/Δy eq(i), where Δx = x(2)-x(1) & Δy = y(2)-y(1),
now using this equation we could compute successive points that lie on the line. But then this is the discrete world of raster graphics - so we require integral coordinates.

In simple DDA eq(i) is transformed to m=eΔx/eΔy where **e**, call it the increment factor, is a positive real number. since putting the same number in numerator and denominator does not change anything - but if suitably chosen - it can help us in generating discrete points thereby reducing the overload of having to round off the resultant points.

Basically what we need to do is: increment the coordinates by a fixed small amount, beginning from the starting point, and each time we have a new point progressing towards the end point.

In simple DDA - *e* is chosen as 1/max(|Δx|,|Δy|) such that one of the coordinate is integral and only the other coordinate has to be rounded. i.e. P(i+1) = P(i)+(1,Round(e*Δy)) here one coordinate is being incremented by 1 and the other by e*Δy

> In symmetric DDA - *e* is chosen such that *though* both the co-ordinates of the resultant points has to be rounded off, it can be done so very efficiently, thus quickly.

Specifically *e* is chosen as 1/2^n where 2^(n-1) <= max(|Δx|,|Δy|) < 2^n. In other words the length of the line is taken to be 2^n aligned. The increments for the two coordinates are e*Δx and e*Δy. With suitably chosen initial fraction part of the beginning coordinates: this causes the points to be generated as mixed fractions whose fractional parts are in a **cyclic series**, i.e. they repeat over a small length. The resultant coordinates can thus easily be rounded off based on two fixed length look-up tables, one for each coordinate.

refer http://w3.msi.vxu.se/~gsu/DAB726-Ht06/Symm-DDA.pdf for an example.
Notice the cyclic repetition in the fractional part of the resultant coordinates.